# In The Great Gatsby, is Nick Carraway's name intentional?

Tags: character-analysis, name-significance, f-scott-fitzgerald, the-great-gatsby

Nick's surname sounds a lot like care-away, and I've seen a number of online sources that state that this Fitzgerald intended for this to be so. I find this hard to believe, considering that Nick isn't characterised as a particularly careless or carefree person. Is there any authoritative source, or good reason, to support his being named 'Carraway'?

Comment: Interestingly, Nick Carraway's *first* name [has been interpreted](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/19403364.1989.11755221) as a reference to Niceros from Petronius's *The Satyricon*, the story from which Fitzgerald's working title *Trimalchio in West Egg* for what later became *The Great Gatsby* was taken.